# Sitemap links indexed duplicate

Tags: php

I have a problem with sitemap listing.
please take a look at this.
[sitemap listing on google](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=site%3awetube.org&oq=site%3awetube.org&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=1763l68688l0l68754l15l15l0l0l0l0l149l1559l5.9l14l0&gs_l=hp.3...1763l68688l0l68755l15l15l0l0l0l0l149l1559l5j9l14l0.frgbld.&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=8229844274f67c87&biw=1298&bih=667)

so the problem is having duplicate for the website links also the title and the description are not showing up

please help me to fix this issue

Comment: what do you mean title and description?  Those aren't part of the sitemap.  Your links are duplicated in the sitemap is probably why they are showing multple times.  http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html

Comment: sorry, title and the description I meant the meta title and description

Comment: if you take a look at the link on google. the title is the link of the page so the meta title is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your site isn't populated properly.  The `<title></title>` isn't populated and neither is the `<meta name="description" content="" />`  If you populate those on all the pages that are in the sitemap they will show up as expected.

Comment: if you get inside the page you will have a title and description.

Comment: Robert, Google etc. is correct. You use empty <title></title> (just view page source yourself) thus are not defining pages titles in a way used by search engines.